# Is a utensil used for chillul Shabbos considered non-kosher?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, kashrut-kosher, cooking-bishul

If a Jew cooks on Shabbos, the [Shulchan Aruch OC (318:1)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.318.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says

> המבשל בשבת [או שעשה א' משאר מלאכות] [טור] במזיד אסור לו לעולם ולאחרים
> מותר למ"ש מיד - One who cooks food on Shabbos [or performs any one of
> the other forbidden acts on Shabbos], if done intentionally, the food
> is forbidden to eat forever, but other people are permitted to eat the
> food immediately after Shabbos.

What is the halachic status of this utensil now? Does it need to be kashered? (What if it was someone else's utensil: do we say the person cannot forbid another person's utensil in this way?)

Of course if this becomes practical [CYLOR](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi)

Comment: No http://www.kosherveyosher.com/shabbos-food-shops.html http://www.eretzhemdah.org/newsletterArticle.asp?lang=en&pageid=48&cat=7&newsletter=1016&article=3858

Answer (score 1):

The Mishna Brura ([318:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.318.1?lang=bi&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.318.4&lang2=bi)) brings the Magen Avraham in the name of the Rashba that **even the pot in which one cooked on Shabbat becomes forbidden for the person who cooked** because it has absorbed (the flavor of) a substance that is forbidden for him (in the case one cooked for a healthy individual, not if done for a sick person).

Mishna Brura Ohr Olam (p. 10, note ii) comments that the pot is only forbidden to the person who cooked, as the pot absorbed flavor forbidden for him. Others may eat the food cooked in this pot since the food was not forbidden to them.

As such the utensil would need to be kashered to be reused by the person who cooked by mistake.

But of course, small details can make a big difference, so anyone facing that situation should ask his or her Rabbi for a specific ruling.

Comment: Worth pointing out that Sefardim do not follow this opinion. See Yalkut Yosef.